# Long name aliases for file and directory paths in emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, bookmarks

I read in the Emacs [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/RegFiles.html#RegFiles) that Emacs supports storing file names in registers that allows a user to quickly retrieve them via the command `C-x r j r`, where `r` is the name of the register. However, this is apparently limited to single character register names.

E.g. The following example works:

```
(set-register ?c '(file . "/gd/gnu/emacs/19.0/src/ChangeLog"))
```

i.e. it allows me to visit the file ChageLog above by just typing `C-x r j z`.

However, if I try to store the path to the above file in a register with a longer name, as in:

```
(set-register ?clog '(file . "/gd/gnu/emacs/19.0/src/ChangeLog"))
```

I get the following error message from he Lisp interpreter:

> Invalid read syntax: "?"

My question then is: Is there a (easy) way of storing file names (and directory paths) in emacs using long name aliases, so that I can quickly visit them? (for editing a file, or loading it in dired).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Bookmarks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html).

Comment: Thank you huaiyuan. I am looking into this, but it looks like Bookmarks' main feature is to give the user the ability to record positions you can jump to later. How can I use Bookmarks to store a pre-defined path that I can enter by hand, and that would persist across Emacs sessions?

Comment: Do you want to remember the file *path* (e.g. for yanking), or do you want to visit the file (or directory). If the latter, then bookmarks is definitely what you want. Visit a file/dir, then `C-x r m (enter a name) RET` to save it. If you now kill that buffer, you can visit it with `C-x r b (bookmark name) RET`. Bookmarks are persistent -- Emacs will ask you if you want to save your bookmarks on exit (or you can use `M-x bookmark-save` to do so immediately).

Comment: Are you asking how to enter the location of a bookmark by hand, without visiting the file etc.? If so, [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkingWithoutVisiting)'s the answer ([Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus)). Also, you can always use command `bookmark-relocate` to change the target file (path) associated with a bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

Registers in Emacs are designed to be accessed with single key presses, so they are named by characters. The ?x syntax is a character syntax. You could save paths in normal variables, or use a hash-table to avoid polluting the variable namespace, but I do not know a preexisting package to do this and only this.

I believe that the more common use case is to just keep files you want to access quickly/often open, and persist [the session state](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html). Switching between buffers can be made more convenient with something like [iswitch](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IswitchBuffers).

I also do not see why [Bookmarks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bookmarks.html) do not fit your use case. If you really want to type the path by hand `(add-to-list 'bookmark-alist '(bookmarkname (filename . "/path/to/your/file")))` appears to work, although visiting the file once and saving a bookmark is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can bookmark a file without actually visiting it.  Sounds like that's what you're asking for: a way to specify the absolute file name and get a bookmark to it (so you can use the shorter, bookmark name).

**Bookmark+** is what you want:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkingWithoutVisiting

[bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks)[bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark)